# How to detect a blank line when inputing information

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Currently I'm working on the 11057 - Exact Sum problem from Online Judge and I'm struggling to make my code accept one or more entries. I was thinking of making a scanner which reads blank lines, and if the second time it does it, its empty, then it would stop, only allowing to the user to input 1 entry. but this doesn't work and I don't know how else to code it, please help.

```
public void readEntry() {
        boolean stillReading=true;
        String answer="";
       while(stillReading) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                bookPrices.add(sc.nextInt());
            }
            Collections.sort(bookPrices);
            sc.nextLine();
            m = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            answer+=printMsg();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (sc.nextLine() == null) {
                stillReading = false;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
```

i think the problem is here but im not sure

```
 m = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            answer+=printMsg();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (sc.nextLine() == null) {
                stillReading = false;
            }
```

the scanner is declares and everything else works perfectly
This is the whole code

```
package ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    Scanner sc;
    private int n, m, start;
    private List<Integer> bookPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Main() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.readEntry();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> search(int f,int duplicates) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = bookPrices.size() - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> sumCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> howClose = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bookPrices.size(); i++) {
            start = bookPrices.get(i);
            while (low <= high) {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;
                if(start+bookPrices.get(mid)==f) {
                    if(duplicates==1) {
                        if (bookPrices.get(mid) - start >= 0) {
                            sumCombinations.add(start);
                            sumCombinations.add(bookPrices.get(mid));
                            howClose.add(bookPrices.get(mid) - start);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if (bookPrices.get(mid) - start > 0) {
                            sumCombinations.add(start);
                            sumCombinations.add(bookPrices.get(mid));
                            howClose.add(bookPrices.get(mid) - start);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (start + bookPrices.get(mid) < f) {
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
            }
            low = 0;
            high = bookPrices.size() - 1;
        }

        Collections.sort(howClose);
        for (int i = 0; i < sumCombinations.size(); i++) {
            if (sumCombinations.get(i + 1) - sumCombinations.get(i) == howClose.get(0)) {
                answer.add(sumCombinations.get(i));
                answer.add(sumCombinations.get(i + 1));
            }
            i++;
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public void readEntry() {
        boolean stillReading=true;
        String answer="";
       while(stillReading) {
            n = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                bookPrices.add(sc.nextInt());
            }
            Collections.sort(bookPrices);
            sc.nextLine();
            m = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            answer+=printMsg();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (sc.nextLine() == null) {
                stillReading = false;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public String printMsg(){
        String msg="";
        boolean duplicates=false;
        ArrayList<Integer> prices=null;
        for(int i=0;i<bookPrices.size();i++) {
            if (Collections.frequency(bookPrices, bookPrices.get(i))>1) {
                duplicates=true;
            }
        }
        if(duplicates==true) {
            prices = search(m,1);
        }
        else if(duplicates==false){
            prices = search(m,2);
        }
        if (prices.size()>0) {
            msg+="Peter should buy books whose prices are " + prices.get(0) + " and " + prices.get(1);
            msg+="\n";
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, if i remove the while loop, my code works for one entry, but i need to work for 1 or more

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged this, the thing that is stopping your readEntry method is last IF block

```
if (sc.nextLine() == null) {
            stillReading = false;
        }
```

This needs to be more precise as blank line is not equal to null. Right now this never equals null and it loops forever. One example would be

```
String nextLine;
if ((nextLine = sc.nextLine()) == null || nextLine.trim().length() == 0) {
            stillReading = false;
        }
```